# Handling ActionErrors in tiles

Tags: java, struts, tiles

I am using tiles in my struts 1 application.

I have a login page in one of the tiles and I have a validate method in my `ActionForm`, which does some validation on the login name. In case of validation error the error message is shown but the login page with error is displayed as standalone -- that is, the tiles structure is not shown.

How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Answer (score 1):

In your action definition, you probably specified the login.jsp instead of the login tile name in the input parameter:

```
<action path="/login"
        type="..."
        name="loginForm"
        scope="request"
        input="/login.jsp"
        validate="true" />
```

should be

```
<action path="/login"
        type="..."
        name="loginForm"
        scope="request"
        input="login.tile.name"
        validate="true" />
```